# Does copper react differently with different people?

Tags: medical-science, biology, natural-remedies, chemistry

One of my friends and I have developed a habit of drinking water from only copper vessels as I have [read](http://www.thehealthsite.com/diseases-conditions/10-benefits-of-drinking-water-from-a-copper-vessel-p214/) several benefits of drinking from that. But I observed one strange phenomenon during past few months. Even if both of us wash our vessels on the same day still my vessel gets darker and more stained than his, almost always within a day or two.  On the other hand, his vessel keeps looking shining and less stained. I know these stains are results of oxidation, but still why do they react differently being with different people ?

[ **PS** : *We had bought our vessels on same date from the same shop, both of us stay in the same dorm room, eat the same food, and have very similar living habits* ]

Comment: This seems to be a question for [chemistry.se], but I doubt it is answerable over there: too many variables. They still may come from two production batches. Your skins will differ. Are they stored the same?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any doubtful claims to investigate. Please edit it to reference a notable claim and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).

Comment: To @Oddthinking: Sorry if I have posted in incorrect place, could you please tell me where would this question be suitable?

Comment: The comments are not an invitation to speculate about answers. Please stick to issues of how we can fix the question, or take it to chat.

Comment: @PointNetworks: You added a link to a page with many [spurious!] claims. If you want us to address one (not all) of those, it would be on topic. The issue of whether your washing up regime is the same as your friends is off-topic though.

Comment: I guess I have posted my question in incorrect forum. I actually did not want to verify any claim or investigate anything. What I wanted was to know possible reasons behind happening in my question. If possible could any of you please redirect/forward my question to right forum. Thanks